# Mscgen grammar for PegKit

Tags: pegkit

Is anyone aware of an existing grammar definition of [Mscgen](http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/) syntax that will work with [PegKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit)? I had a look in the "res" folder but most of those don't seem to work.

Here is a sample

```
# MSC for some fictional process
msc {
  hscale = "2";

  a,b,c;

  a->b [ label = "ab()" ] ;
  b->c [ label = "bc(TRUE)"];
  c=>c [ label = "process(1)" ];
  c=>c [ label = "process(2)" ];
  ...;
  c=>c [ label = "process(n)" ];
  c=>c [ label = "process(END)" ];
  a<<=c [ label = "callback()"];
  ---  [ label = "If more to run", ID="*" ];
  a->a [ label = "next()"];
  a->c [ label = "ac1()\nac2()"];
  b<-c [ label = "cb(TRUE)"];
  b->b [ label = "stalled(...)"];
  a<-b [ label = "ab() = FALSE"];
}
```

Comment: Developer of PEGKit here. I'm not aware of any Mscgen grammars. I had never heard of this before (although it looks nice).

Comment: Thanks for the response and the nice took PEGKit. I guess time for me to try and figure it out.

Comment: There's the MscGen PEG(.js) grammar I wrote last year for mscgen_js. It should get you started. [Direct link](https://github.com/sverweij/mscgen_js/blob/master/src/script/parse/peg/mscgenparser.pegjs)

Great to see someone else working on an implementation of MscGen!

Comment: Thanks @Sander I have been referencing your code already ;)